# Remove gap between input and span tags

Tags: html, css

Hi,

**EDIT**:I followed the suggestions that had been mentioned in the following comments.Then,Its working in IE well,but problem still persists in Google Chrome...Could somebody help me....*Here is the code that came after changes*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .inputBox{
   white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
  }
   .inputBox input{
    border:1px solid #9AAABD;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px #b7c2d0;
    float:left;
   }
   .iconHolder{
    background:#fff url('ComboBoxArrow_regular.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width:12px;
    height:19px;
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
}
  .iconHolder:hover{
     background:#007DC0 url('ComboBoxArrow_hover.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <span class="inputBox">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="iconHolder"></span>
  </span>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here are the two images:
[image: ComboBoxArrow_hover][image: ComboBoxArrow_regular]

I want to develop a drop down list box.I am using input filed and a `<span>` tag which will hold the `down arrow icon` to get the list box look.
 The problem is there is an unnecessary gap between input field and span which is really ugly.Can that gap be removed? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Vax/) is the sample application. Here I used `V` for test purpose but actually there should be an image.

**Note**: The span's height should be equal to input's tag,And if we change the resolution of the browser thier alignment should not be distorted....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the Image to the EDIT

Comment: I have added those two images : U can see black down arrow and other one is white so that it is not visible..

Comment: Did you get the same error or is it working fine for your side?

Comment: Check the Code Now. Hope it's OK for you

Comment: Hi,sorry for the disturbance.Its working fine..but I got another problem..Since dropdown is a form field,user may want to align this field in the form like in div tag or table or keep them side by side without any alignment..Now the problem is I am unable to align the element since it is floated to left always I guess...Can you please check this by adding two fields side by side and one in a table cell.....

Comment: Could you post a Fiddle for this?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ku8mC/ .But in fiddle it looks fine.So please check it in your system browsers.

Comment: hey, check out the update-2. Its working fine for me in chrome and firefox

Comment: Yeah it working in Chrome but problem still there for IE...What changes did you apply to make it work in Chrome....Do you have any idea that why doesn't it work in IE too?...Thanks a lot for your valuable time and help....

Comment: Let me give a try in IE. Actually i don't have installed IE in my PC. I removed it for few other purposes... :)

Comment: Ok,Looking forward for your response....

Comment: Hey, i was out of Station. I just checked it today. Its working fine for me in IE 7,8,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/28v4K/1/)**

Here is the Bit of Change to your CSS,

```
.inputBox{
   white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
  }
   .inputBox input{
    border-left:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-top:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-right:1px solid #b7c2d0;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px #b7c2d0;
    float:left;
   }
   .iconHolder{
    background:#007DC0 url('arrow.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width:12px;
    height:18px;
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left;
}
  .iconHolder:hover{
     background:#ff6600 url('arrow2.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  }
```

**EDITED**

**​Google Chrome Update** : Add Zero Margin (`margin:0;`) to the Text Box. Works well in Chrome for me.

```
.inputBox{
}
.inputBox input{
    border-left:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-top:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9AAABD;
    border-right:1px solid #b7c2d0;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px #b7c2d0;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
.iconHolder{
    background:#007DC0 url('arrow2.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width:15px;
    height:20px;
    float:left; 
}
.iconHolder:hover{
    background:#ff6600 url('arrow.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

**UPDATE-2** : The Entire HTML Page with many similar Drop Downs.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .inputBox{
            }
            .inputBox input{
                border-left:1px solid #9AAABD;
                border-top:1px solid #9AAABD;
                border-bottom:1px solid #9AAABD;
                border-right:1px solid #b7c2d0;
                box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px #b7c2d0;
                float:left;
                margin:0;
            }
            .iconHolder{
                background:#007DC0 url('arrow2.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
                width:15px;
                height:20px;
                float:left; 
            }
            .iconHolder:hover{
                background:#ff6600 url('arrow.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="inputBox">
            <input type="text">
            <span class="iconHolder"></span>
        </span>

        <span class="inputBox">
            <input type="text">
            <span class="iconHolder"></span>
        </span>

        <br/>

        <span class="inputBox">
            <input type="text">
            <span class="iconHolder"></span>
        </span>

        <br/>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>  
                    <span class="inputBox">
                        <input type="text">
                        <span class="iconHolder"></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="inputBox">
                        <input type="text">
                        <span class="iconHolder"></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check it in Google Chrome , It works fine IE but not in Chrome,problem still persists there..Can you please revise once in Chrome

Comment: Actually i did it in Chrome. Works fine in the latest Chrome for me

Comment: I am editing my question by providing my code.I included whatever code you had given..But its not working fine in Chrome...Can you please check whatz wrong in my code..

Answer (score 6):

Don't do anything in code. Just remove the space between input field and span in HTML. Write it as -

```
<span class="inputBox">
    <input type="text"><span class="iconHolder">V</span>
</span>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Vax/3/)

EDIT:

or make the elements float left -

```
input, .iconHolder{ float: left; }

.iconHolder{
    background:#007DC0 url('arrow.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width:12px;
    height:18px;
}
```

[**Another Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Vax/5/)

Comment: Yeah,you r right..But in my case I cannot remove that space since it is generated by server....Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hi now they are two method

firs is give to `float left;` of your `input` and `iconHolder`

```
.inputBox input, .iconHolder{
float:left;
}
```

---

> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Vax/2/)

---

**Second is**  define your span `display:inline-block;` or `vertical-align:top;` and give to **parent**

`font-size:0;` or **child** give `font-size:12px;` according to your design

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Vax/1/)***

Comment: Yeah,it is floated properly but as you show in the demo , that span got smaller and it cannot be set to input height...is there any solution to set the height?

Comment: +1 for parent - font-size:0; and child - font-size: 12px.. I used em to px converter [gist](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Pixel-Em-Converter/blob/master/pxem.jQuery.js) to calculate the outer height before making the span font size 0px.

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute to both of them 
 float: left;